# How to write documentdb query to fetch data from collction with multiple ids?

Tags: mysql, sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have two collections in documentdb database.

```
1. users collection
2. chats collection
```

users's collection has multiple documents with user details, including userid, password, name, etc.

chats's collection has multiple documents with userid and chats data, so its easy to get chats with particular userid.

if I want to fetch one record from document with chatId or userid then documentdb query is working fine.

But now my question is that, in my chats's collection each document has user's array which contains object with userid & username, so now I have fetch 1 document from chats collection with chatid, which has gave me users's array.

```
users = [{
  userid: 'user-1',
  username: 'piyush1'
},{
  userid: 'user-2',
  username: 'piyush2'
},{
  userid: 'user-3',
  username: 'piyush3'
},{
  userid: 'user-4',
  username: 'piyush4'
}];
```

now I want to fetch all user's data from user's collection by giving this array to query, here in this array there are four user's ids so if I give this array to query then it should return me documents of all these users from user collection,

How can I write this query in documentdb?

Note: I don't want to use loop.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `in` filter.

For example,

```
select *
from users
where id in ('user1_id', 'user2_id')
```

You can try the query in the playground here https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo

```
SELECT food.id,
    food.description,
    food.tags,
    food.foodGroup,
    food.manufacturerName,
    food.version
FROM food
WHERE food.id in ('14026','14145')
```

which returns 2 food records

Comment: select *
from users
where userid in ({"userid": "bLY4QyqJ", "username": ""}, {"userid": "W2yYE50V", "username": ""}, {"userid":"UFzVDTkS"}, {"userid": "7OpWfWxR"})

I have array something like this with objects. I want to search all users based on all userids of array.

Comment: You can transform your object to get the ids you need, and I think it is not hard.

Comment: you are right but I can not modify my array that is 1st restriction for me, so I have to fetch data based on given array.